# edit parquet file metadata

Tags: metadata, parquet, pyarrow

I have two pieces of software I want to connect, one writes out a parquet file with certain metadata, the other reads in parquet files with certain metadata. There is however a small inconsistency between the output format of one and the input format of the other. So I'm looking for a way to edit one line in the custom metadata that part 1 wrote, before passing on the parquet file to the other program. How can I do this? What would be a way for me to make a parquet file identical to the original, but just with one line changed in the metadata?

The parquet files are dumped by `pyarrow` under the hood, so that was my first attempt, but I'm not able to find a function that just makes a file with identical metadata with one line modified.

Comment: Are you able to alter step 1 to modify the metadata before you write?  Or do you have to use a read / modify / write solution that modifies the file between 1 and 2?